# How to start arena on Ubuntu linux

Tags: engines, linux

I would like to be able to play the Stockfish engine using the Arena GUI.  I consulted the ["playarena" site](http://www.playwitharena.com/?Download:Arena_for_Linux) and the only instructions were to download and unpack the .tar.gz file.  I did this but there is no makefile in the directory so I am not able to compile the Arena application with a 'make' command. what steps should I take to get Arena working with the Stockfish engine? I am new to linux and would appreciate any help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arena is not an open source program, so you won't be able to compile the source code.

Do you see `Arena_x86_64_linux`? Just run it and play chess.

Comment: Thank you, I now know how to check for an executable file in the folder and will in the future.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sometimes an `error while loading shared libraries: libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` message can happen. Then a `sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0` and re-running the `Arena_x86_64_linux` should do the job. Comment : I remark a black area instead of the usual chessboard but it's clickage nevertheless and pieces and squares appears as you click them. This is on `ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64`.